# Cover letter for applying via Email

Tags: application, postdocs, application-cover-letter

I am going to apply for a postdoc position. Applicants are asked to send their CV,research statement, name of referees etc as a single PDF file directly mailing to the "principle investigator" of that project. I was wondering whether I need to add my cover letter into that PDF file or just write it in my email itself.